# gcloud SQL postgres - FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am seing those errors in cloud sql Postgres logs.

Its a small 1 cpu, 4Gb of ram instance yet this is a bit troublesome.
I do not see any `max_connections` in the customizable flags that could allow me to bypass this error.

The app is a simple Django service with very little queries and load not even exposed to the public.

The immediate solution is for me to start using db connection pooling with pgbouncer or a Django app but that adds up a bit of complexity.

```
 max_connections 
-----------------
 100
```

Do we have a way to increase this number?

PS: After digging a bit it seems to come from the use of gevent workers with gunicorn. It was stable < 20 connections before that.

Nevertheless, in case of traffic surge it would be good to know if `max_connections` can be controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONN_MAX_AGE: 0` when using gevent.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: now you can set the max_connections setting via Cloud SQL Flags. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-m

---

This was my answer in the time of writing the question:

There is currently no way to increase a limit, but we are aware of this problem. Please follow [Issue 37271935](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37271935) on our issue tracker.

Comment: This issue has been fixed by Google! Now there is a way - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-m . @rvs, good find! Please update your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

See the relation between memory and Max concurrent connections here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/pricing-access-limits

I solved my problem using Postgresql (for now).

I set up more memory for the database